# Why isn't Php not loading values from php.ini?

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I have a LAMP setup. I have set the `upload_max_filesize` directive to 100M and `post_max_size` to 100M. However on executing phpinfo() the result reveals that maximum limit is still set to 2M (which is the default value of upload_max_filesize).

The changes were made in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and restarting Apache server didn't help.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you try adding `<?php echo php_ini_loaded_file() ?>` to a file on your server and then open it in a browser?

Comment: Did you try restarting your LAMP Server ?

Comment: "restarting Apache server didn't help"